# iOS SwiftUI: Correctly stack NavigationView with ScrollView and ZStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I've been playing around with SwiftUI and I can't seem to stack `NavigationView` correctly with `ScrollView` and `ZStack`.

I'm trying to achieve a view with a `.black` background. Code below:

**MainView.swift**

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ChildView()
    }
}
```

**ChildView.swift**

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        ScrollView {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gives me a black background but breaks the navigation bar behaviour.

**How it looks:**
[image]

**How it should look:**
[image]

So it seems like the the navigation doesn't go from the `scrollEdgeAppearance` to `standardAppearance` when scrolling.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so, please accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `ScrollView` up as far as possible, otherwise the header animation will not work. The following code does what you want:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<40) { _ in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Discover")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ChildView()
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve a completely black background, even if you scroll up the bottom, you have to fiddle around in `UINavigationController`. While there, I also changed the navigation bar colors to achieve your look and feel. Note that this doesn't keep track of whether the user enabled dark mode or not.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark

        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the ZStack the first child in your example?

Comment: No not quite, when scrolling to the bottom of the scroll view one sees the background being white still. So seems like the underlying view color is white and the overlaying view black. I’m trying to achieve a completely black background. Any ideas?

Comment: See edit. I think it does what you want. It's a very interesting question.

Comment: Cool, where do you add the extension? I mean in what file in order to keep the code clean

Comment: It's customary to put it in a separate file with a special name, and this question describes it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26319660